# Why is my cookie being stored for one year?

Tags: php, cookies

I'm working on a little php script to set a referer cookie.  It is supposed to disappear when the browser closes, but when the browser is loaded back up, the cookie persists.  What am I doing wrong?

```
   /**
 * @file set_referer_cookie.php
 *
 * @author Nate Yanez
 * sets a temporary cookie to track lead sources such as PPC campaigns
 */

$ref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if ((!isset($_COOKIE['http_referer_cookie'])) && (strpos($ref, 'examplewebsite.domain.com') === FALSE)){
    setcookie('http_referer_cookie',$ref);
}
return;
```

Comment: Show us a screenshot of the console where it shows it being set for one year

Comment: also HTTP_REFERER is close to useless. browser set, often stripped 100% fake-able

Comment: What is a good alternative for HTTP_REFERER?

Comment: there isent one, http is a stateless protocol, what specificly are you doing?

Comment: Show the corresponding headers

Comment: Attempting to track lead sources

Comment: unless the sender site modifies the url to say there source, expect a large number to be blank or fake.

Comment: Could you share the `Set-Cookie` header?

Comment: I'm looking to track hits from advertising campaigns from Google/Bing/Yahoo etc. and log them to the DB.  Where do I find the "Set-Cookie" header?

Comment: It could be that the chrome extension I'm using for cookies is falsely saying that the cookie expires in a year, but it is not being removed when I exit the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly setting it to expire when the browser closes by setting the third parameter to zero.

`setcookie('http_referer_cookie',$ref,0);`

This is the default value, but I am thinking something is modifying it, a browser extension maybe? To check that theory try using a different browser and see if error persists.

Comment: This appears to be working.  I think it might be a problem with my chrome browser.  Firefox is removing the cookie when the session closes.

Comment: k, seems like something was overwriting the cookie expiry in chrome - asserting default values always helps...

Comment: Well to clarify, the problem seems to persist in chrome, but if it is working in firefox, that is good enough for me.

Comment: Thats cool. Also just in case you want, in Chrome you can go to Tools > Developer Tools > Resources > Cookies and check the Expires/Max-Age set for the cookie in question

Comment: Right, when I did that, it would say that it expires when session ends... but that wasn't actually happening.  It was persisting.

Comment: Hmm...thats a tricky weasel. Not sure what is going on, but I can most certainly say something in Chrome is messing up the mojo. Maybe you can try reinstalling a fresh copy? The code however, is fine AFAIK

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're seeing this behavior, but try setting expire to time() + some explicit small value, ie

```
setcookie("http_referer_cookie", $value, time()+3600);
```

Comment: Ohh well.  Two hours should be long enough for my purposes, although it is terribly vexing.